# Chrome: Color rendering inaccurately when an input is in focus

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, chromium

I'm rendering background glow using CSS. However, when the user focuses on the input element, the background rendering quality drops and visual artifacts are very obvious. The gradient becomes kind of "segmented", looking like several circular rings rather than a continuous, smooth gradient.

Is it possible to force rendering quality in CSS?

I've created a codepen demonstration of the issue here: https://codepen.io/hykilpikonna/pen/VwRRYXV, which is the following code. Note: This issue only appears on Chrome or Chromium browsers and not Firefox, and you need to turn up your brightness to see it.

```css
.main {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: #242424;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  inset: -500px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: radial-gradient(50% 50% at 50% 50%, rgba(158, 110, 230, 0.28) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  
  pointer-events: none;
}

input {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  
</div>
```

Screenshot: User not focused on the input and the background renders fine:

[image]

Screenshot: User focused on the input and the background quality drops:

[image]